# file manipulation: removing every occurence of a string execpt the first occurence after a certain different pattern

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I would like to remove lines in a file, which occur more than once, but would like to keep certain ones. How do i do this?

This is a part of my file, which i would like to change:

```
§M: 1, K: 2
    name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 88378.00, 23272.00,  646.00,  1525.00,  241.00, 17447.00,     1, 0.26, 4.71, 5.07 
    name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 32083.00, 17690.00,  148.00,    28.00,  116.00, 6437.00,     1, 0.55, 25.96, 4.98 
    name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31342.00, 17690.00,  161.00,    23.00,  100.00, 6125.00,     1, 0.56, 36.46, 5.12 

   name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Blitz2D, 0.00, 33418.00, 17933.00,  168.00,    83.00,  109.00, 6473.00,     1, 0.54, 12.50, 5.16 

     name, time,     cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 176180.00, 60830.00, 1586.00,  3040.00,  546.00, 36306.00,     1, 0.35, 1.21, 4.85 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 39599.00, 21641.00,  258.00,    41.00,  169.00, 7962.00,     1, 0.55, 4.21, 4.97 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 36483.00, 21641.00,  261.00,     5.00,  110.00, 7323.00,     1, 0.59, 5.84, 4.98 

   name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 47271.00, 24427.00,  296.00,   298.00,  143.00, 9354.00,     1, 0.52, 2.81, 5.05 
   name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 31979.00, 18101.00,  166.00,    19.00,  100.00, 6313.00,     1, 0.57, 16.23, 5.07 
   name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 32383.00, 18101.00,  175.00,    38.00,   96.00, 6513.00,     1, 0.56, 18.09, 4.97 




§M: 2, K: 2
    name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31548.00, 17689.00,  149.00,    20.00,  101.00, 6112.00,     1, 0.56, 33.77, 5.16 
    name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31404.00, 17689.00,  161.00,     0.00,   95.00, 6105.00,     1, 0.56, 41.82, 5.14 
    name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31060.00, 17689.00,  167.00,     8.00,   93.00, 6145.00,     1, 0.57, 38.41, 5.05 

   name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Blitz2D, 0.00, 32130.00, 18122.00,  155.00,    47.00,  113.00, 6359.00,     1, 0.56, 16.87, 5.05 

     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 42370.00, 22410.00,  245.00,   105.00,  193.00, 8393.00,     1, 0.53, 3.53, 5.05 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 37526.00, 21853.00,  264.00,    26.00,  119.00, 7474.00,     1, 0.58, 5.25, 5.02 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 37091.00, 21853.00,  247.00,    22.00,  107.00, 7377.00,     1, 0.59, 5.74, 5.03 

   name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 55863.00, 25323.00,  321.00,   434.00,  166.00, 11266.00,     1, 0.45, 2.17, 4.96 
   name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 34626.00, 18984.00,  198.00,    47.00,  111.00, 6661.00,     1, 0.55, 9.93, 5.20 
   name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 32862.00, 18984.00,  191.00,    17.00,   97.00, 6572.00,     1, 0.58, 11.99, 5.00
```

This pattern continues. What i would like to have is, that the line `name, ...` is keep after every `§M: *,K:*` but after that it is deleted, until pattern 2 appers again.

In the end it should hopefully look something like this:

```
§M: 1, K: 2
    name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 88378.00, 23272.00,  646.00,  1525.00,  241.00, 17447.00,     1, 0.26, 4.71, 5.07 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 32083.00, 17690.00,  148.00,    28.00,  116.00, 6437.00,     1, 0.55, 25.96, 4.98 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31342.00, 17690.00,  161.00,    23.00,  100.00, 6125.00,     1, 0.56, 36.46, 5.12 

Blitz2D, 0.00, 33418.00, 17933.00,  168.00,    83.00,  109.00, 6473.00,     1, 0.54, 12.50, 5.16 

XTensor2D, 0.00, 176180.00, 60830.00, 1586.00,  3040.00,  546.00, 36306.00,     1, 0.35, 1.21, 4.85 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 39599.00, 21641.00,  258.00,    41.00,  169.00, 7962.00,     1, 0.55, 4.21, 4.97 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 36483.00, 21641.00,  261.00,     5.00,  110.00, 7323.00,     1, 0.59, 5.84, 4.98 

Eigen2D, 0.00, 47271.00, 24427.00,  296.00,   298.00,  143.00, 9354.00,     1, 0.52, 2.81, 5.05 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 31979.00, 18101.00,  166.00,    19.00,  100.00, 6313.00,     1, 0.57, 16.23, 5.07 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 32383.00, 18101.00,  175.00,    38.00,   96.00, 6513.00,     1, 0.56, 18.09, 4.97 




§M: 2, K: 2
    name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31548.00, 17689.00,  149.00,    20.00,  101.00, 6112.00,     1, 0.56, 33.77, 5.16 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31404.00, 17689.00,  161.00,     0.00,   95.00, 6105.00,     1, 0.56, 41.82, 5.14 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31060.00, 17689.00,  167.00,     8.00,   93.00, 6145.00,     1, 0.57, 38.41, 5.05 

Blitz2D, 0.00, 32130.00, 18122.00,  155.00,    47.00,  113.00, 6359.00,     1, 0.56, 16.87, 5.05 

XTensor2D, 0.00, 42370.00, 22410.00,  245.00,   105.00,  193.00, 8393.00,     1, 0.53, 3.53, 5.05 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 37526.00, 21853.00,  264.00,    26.00,  119.00, 7474.00,     1, 0.58, 5.25, 5.02 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 37091.00, 21853.00,  247.00,    22.00,  107.00, 7377.00,     1, 0.59, 5.74, 5.03 

Eigen2D, 0.00, 55863.00, 25323.00,  321.00,   434.00,  166.00, 11266.00,     1, 0.45, 2.17, 4.96 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 34626.00, 18984.00,  198.00,    47.00,  111.00, 6661.00,     1, 0.55, 9.93, 5.20 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 32862.00, 18984.00,  191.00,    17.00,   97.00, 6572.00,     1, 0.58, 11.99, 5.00
```

Is there a sed formula for this or one in awk? Please maybe explain what your lines do, i would like to understand it. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: as i do not have any really experience in sed or awk, i havent tried anything, as i would just do it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
# awk is a line oriented program.
# for each line in the input file, following procedures are run.
/^§/ { f = 1 } # if input line begins with a `§', flag is up
/^ *name,/ {   # if input line begins with zero or more spaces followed by `name,';
  if (f) {     # and if flag is up;
    print      # print this line
    f = 0      # put flag down
  }
  next         # break the cycle irrespective of flag's status, read a new line and start over
}
1 # when this is reached, print input line
```

Usage:

```
awk '/^§/{f=1} /^ *name,/{if(f){print;f=0} next} 1' file
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, could you maybe explain what it does, i get the part with the paragraph-char, and why the first occurence after that is not deleted, but i dont understand what the rest after that does

Comment: @CleboSevic updated my answer with extended comments please read it again, what specific part you don't understand?

Comment: Basically everything is understandable(thanks to your comments :thumbs_up:), but the 1 baffles me a bit, does that mean, taht every line that does not fullfill one of the conditions gets printed anyways?

Comment: @CleboSevic nope. if awk reaches `1`, it prints the input line. in above script, if input line begins with `name,` and flag is down, we are preventing awk from reaching `1` using `next` procedure. Remove it and run the script to see the difference.

Comment: ok, that clears it up for me, thanks again, you saved me a lot of trouble

Comment: @CleboSevic Welcome, my English kinda sucks so I could not explain it as clearly as I wanted, sorry

Comment: well i feel the same about mine, so i was not sure if i just understood i wrong. And it was more than good enough to be understandable

Answer (score 2):

Treat your input as a series of records whose first line starts at `§`. Now just print the 2nd line of each record (i.e. the first `name` line in each record) and every line that doesn't start with `name`:

```
$ awk '/^§/{lineNr=0} (++lineNr==2) || (!/^ *name/)' file
§M: 1, K: 2
    name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz
Fastor2D, 0.00, 88378.00, 23272.00,  646.00,  1525.00,  241.00, 17447.00,     1, 0.26, 4.71, 5.07
Fastor2D, 0.00, 32083.00, 17690.00,  148.00,    28.00,  116.00, 6437.00,     1, 0.55, 25.96, 4.98
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31342.00, 17690.00,  161.00,    23.00,  100.00, 6125.00,     1, 0.56, 36.46, 5.12

Blitz2D, 0.00, 33418.00, 17933.00,  168.00,    83.00,  109.00, 6473.00,     1, 0.54, 12.50, 5.16

XTensor2D, 0.00, 176180.00, 60830.00, 1586.00,  3040.00,  546.00, 36306.00,     1, 0.35, 1.21, 4.85
XTensor2D, 0.00, 39599.00, 21641.00,  258.00,    41.00,  169.00, 7962.00,     1, 0.55, 4.21, 4.97
XTensor2D, 0.00, 36483.00, 21641.00,  261.00,     5.00,  110.00, 7323.00,     1, 0.59, 5.84, 4.98

Eigen2D, 0.00, 47271.00, 24427.00,  296.00,   298.00,  143.00, 9354.00,     1, 0.52, 2.81, 5.05
Eigen2D, 0.00, 31979.00, 18101.00,  166.00,    19.00,  100.00, 6313.00,     1, 0.57, 16.23, 5.07
Eigen2D, 0.00, 32383.00, 18101.00,  175.00,    38.00,   96.00, 6513.00,     1, 0.56, 18.09, 4.97




§M: 2, K: 2
    name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31548.00, 17689.00,  149.00,    20.00,  101.00, 6112.00,     1, 0.56, 33.77, 5.16
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31404.00, 17689.00,  161.00,     0.00,   95.00, 6105.00,     1, 0.56, 41.82, 5.14
Fastor2D, 0.00, 31060.00, 17689.00,  167.00,     8.00,   93.00, 6145.00,     1, 0.57, 38.41, 5.05

Blitz2D, 0.00, 32130.00, 18122.00,  155.00,    47.00,  113.00, 6359.00,     1, 0.56, 16.87, 5.05

XTensor2D, 0.00, 42370.00, 22410.00,  245.00,   105.00,  193.00, 8393.00,     1, 0.53, 3.53, 5.05
XTensor2D, 0.00, 37526.00, 21853.00,  264.00,    26.00,  119.00, 7474.00,     1, 0.58, 5.25, 5.02
XTensor2D, 0.00, 37091.00, 21853.00,  247.00,    22.00,  107.00, 7377.00,     1, 0.59, 5.74, 5.03

Eigen2D, 0.00, 55863.00, 25323.00,  321.00,   434.00,  166.00, 11266.00,     1, 0.45, 2.17, 4.96
Eigen2D, 0.00, 34626.00, 18984.00,  198.00,    47.00,  111.00, 6661.00,     1, 0.55, 9.93, 5.20
Eigen2D, 0.00, 32862.00, 18984.00,  191.00,    17.00,   97.00, 6572.00,     1, 0.58, 11.99, 5.00
```

Answer (score -1):

Typical idiom for removing duplicates is:
`awk '!d[$0]++'`.

You could add to it any predicate, which could base on prev line:

```
awk '
  /M:.+, K:/ { last_header_line = NR }
  last_header_line == NR-1 || !d[$0]++ { print }
'
```

Comment: ĉould you explain what this command does, and how i can apply it to my situation? i would also like to keep most of the duplicates, just not the ones after the first occurence in one piece of the file